# <nav> inside modal dialog- what is preferred keyboard focus pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, screen-readers

I am asking this question with screenreader/ keyboard-only users in mind.

I have a main `<nav>` on my page.  I also have a secondary `<nav>` nested inside my modal dialog.

When a user selects an item from my primary `nav`, I reset focus to the skiplinks at the top of the page.

When a user selects an item from my secondary `nav`, should I set focus to the related tabpanel?  Or should I replicate the navigation pattern from my main page i.e. there is a secondary set of skiplinks at the top of my modal and my user can choose to skip to the modal navigation or modal content?

I see a lot of examples for navigation and a lot of examples of modals but none of complex modals that require a nav of their own.

Comment: It seems like your modal has a lot of contents, so maybe it’s not a good solution to put all that inside a modal. You might have issues with scrolling and scaling as well. With Single Page Applications (SPA), the [recommended navigation pattern is to set focus to the first headline within the region that changed contents](https://www.tpgi.com/single-page-applications/#techniques). The skip navigation is not recommended. This should be the solution for both casse.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I am remediating an existing piece of software so I can only ask for design to be redone in scenarios where usability is completely broken. I don't feel this is the case here.  Our SPA follows the "hybrid SPA" pattern in your link.

Comment: I guess you still got your recommendation here then: You should put focus on the tab that changed. It’s quite likely that putting focus on the skip link poses a real usability issue, because the changes might not be announced. The document title changes, I hope (?), but I think it’s not being announced. What feedback does the user receive that the navigation action was executed? if you press “contact”, you want to hear “contact” somewhen, right?

Comment: We are told "internal link", the title of the link and then the title of the new content in the tab panel.  Outside of the dialog we are told "navigated to XYZ page",but not within it.  I'm thinking maybe I should concatenate in the modal title so that we are told "internal link" "create user modal, update details" rather than just "update details", so that the user knows they're still in the modal.  What do you think?

Comment: Does that mean that users can still use the primary navigation while the modal is open?

Comment: No they can't, their focus is trapped in the modal until they exit it. I was just mentioning the primary nav for comparison, as it's more verbose.